# R: Very large multiple loops within loops is taking absolutely too long, what might be other options? How to vectorize this?

Tags: r, performance, loops, large-data

Preceding information that you might help understand the problem:
I have a data/set and or matrix that has 257 columns, with column 257 just a column of zeros for coding purposes.

I need to find what the highest correlation between four - ten indivisual columns using an indivisual linear model for every possible combination. I have been ranking the best fit by the R squared value for each linear model as comparing it to a single column matrix.

I have already completed this task for every combination of 1-3 columns, but when four parameters are used as shown below, R cannot complete the task in a reasonable amount of time, have had the code running for about five days, and its not even close to being done.

The code below is a loop within a loop within a loop... etc, adding another loop for each added parameter used. Currently the code will save the r squared value and the loop number of each loop in a vector if it is within the top ten highest found. I thought doing this would save some memory, and speed it up, however, it did not help at all or not enough.

My question is: Is it possible to speed this up in R, or is there a better language to use? And how would I go about using another language, software? Price? I have only used R in coding before, as I havent done it for long and am an amatuer by a long shot.

I would appreciate any advice! Thanks.

The code is as follows for the example with four parameters, that has taken very long to run

```
#Creating objects for loop run. Overunder is already filled.

overundermatrix <- matrix(0,nrow=length(totalsc),ncol=1)
vectfourparamovun <- c(.01,.001,.0001,.00001,.000001,.0000001,.00000001,.000000001,.0000000001,.00000000001)
vectfourindexovun <- vector("list",10)

#Main Body of Loop
options(warn=-1)
for(n in 3:256){
for(i in 1:254){
for(j in 1:254){
for(a in 1:254){
lm1 <- lm(overundermatrix~data[,n]+data[,(ifelse((n+i)>256,257,(n+i)))]+data[,(ifelse((n+i+j)>256,257,(n+i+j)))]+data[,ifelse((n+i+j+a)>256,257,(n+i+j+a))])
lm1sum <-summary(lm1)
if(lm1sum[[9]]>vectfourparamovun[1:10])
{
vectfourindexovun[[which.min(vectfourparamovun[1:10])]] <- list(c(a,j,i,n))
vectfourparamovun[which.min(vectfourparamovun[1:10])] <- lm1sum[[9]]
}
}
}
}
}
options(warn=0)
```

As you can see, I just want to find every possible combination and create a linear model for it, but it is very long to do. I don't know how to without using loops.

Comment: I strongly suggest you talk to a statistician before trying something that might be considered complete madness and utterly useless. Sorry to be so harsh, but even if this would run, there is literally nothing at all you can do with the result, as the laws of statistics can tell you with 100% certainty that the top ranking you become this way is purely coincidential.

Answer (score 8):

You are doing brute-force model search, which just about any statistically minded person would advise against.  Just because "you can" does not mean "you should".

That said, there are approaches that help with model specification search over a large number of possible mnodels.  This is sometimes called 'small n, large p' (to describe that the number of columns dominates the number of rows) and is a core research topic in statistical genomics.  There are a number of CRAN packages that help with this, and you may want to look at the [CRAN Task View for Machine Learning and Statistical Learning](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/MachineLearning.html).

Finally, if you must proceed with your brute force search, consider

1. replacing `lm()` with faster alternatives such as `lm.fit()` in base R, or `fastLm()` in [RcppArmadillo](http://cran.r-project.org/packages=RcppArmadillo)
2. replacing your core code with a compiled solution; and [Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html) may help.

Answer (score 4):

What you are trying to do will take a very long time, no matter what software you use. Consider, for example, the problem of calculating the highest "R-squared" value for five variables out of your 257 columns.

```
# Number of possible combinations (about 8 billion)
choose(257,5)
# At 1 ms, number of days it would take
choose(257,5) / 1000 / 3600 / 24
# 104 days.
```

As you can see, even if you had a method that fit the model in 1 ms, it would take 104 days to complete.

You should really look into the package BMA. It will find the "best" model fit to your data, using the BIC, a much better criteria than simply the explained variance.